# How to rename a logical value (TRUE or FALSE) with "Yes" or "No" and apply distinct() to FALSE values

Tags: r, rename, dplyr

I have a data.frame with 3 columns: cod, identity and description.

I did:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

dBase %>%
         group_by(identity) %>%
         count(have_na=is.na(description)) %>% 
         rename(Total=n) %>% 
         adorn_totals('row')
```

Result

```
 identity         have_na Total
        1           FALSE     1
        1            TRUE     1
        2           FALSE    11
        2            TRUE     2
    Total               -    15
```

Now I need to use `distinct(cod)` only in "FALSE" values.

And, then, I need to convert the `have_na` column from "TRUE" or "FALSE" with "Yes" or "No".

I can convert to numeric, using `mutate_if(is.logical,as.numeric)`, but I have been failing with character.

What I need:

```
 identity         have_na Total
        1              No     1
        1             Yes     1
        2              No     3
        2             Yes     2
    Total               -     7
```

sample of my data:

```r
structure(list(
cod = c("122", "122", "122","5773", "2801", "2801", "2801", "2801", "0294", "0110", "3959", 
"9018", "9018", "9018", "9017"), 
identity = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1"),
description = c(8299799L, 4623199L, 4683400L, 5211799L, 4771704L, 4789002L, 4789004L, 4729699L, 
NA, NA, NA, 4623106L, 4623109L, 4632003L, 4691500L)), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I don't think R knows how to translate TRUE/FALSE values to a character value. Try mutate(have_na = ifelse(have_na=TRUE, 'YES', 'NO'))

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am not understanding correctly, but this seems to be two different questions.

## 1. `distinct` on `FALSE` values only.

```
dBase %>%
  group_by(cod, identity) %>%
  count(have_na=is.na(description)) %>% 
  rename(Total=n) %>% 
  filter(!have_na) %>%
  mutate(have_na = c("No", "Yes")[have_na + 1L]) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  adorn_totals('row') 
#   cod identity have_na Total
#   122        2      No     3
#  2801        2      No     4
#  5773        2      No     1
#  9017        1      No     1
#  9018        2      No     3
# Total        -       -    12
```

## 2. Rename `FALSE/TRUE` to `"No"/"Yes"`.

I will use the fact that logical values are code internally as integers `0/1` to subset a target vector.

```
dBase %>%
  group_by(cod, identity) %>%
  count(have_na=is.na(description)) %>% 
  rename(Total=n) %>% 
  mutate(have_na = c("No", "Yes")[have_na + 1L]) %>%
  adorn_totals('row')
#   cod identity have_na Total
#  0110        1     Yes     1
#  0294        2     Yes     1
#   122        2      No     3
#  2801        2      No     4
#  3959        2     Yes     1
#  5773        2      No     1
#  9017        1      No     1
#  9018        2      No     3
# Total        -       -    15
```

## Edit.

After the last comment by user RxT, I believe the following code does what the question asks for.
It creates an intermediate data set and filters first the `FALSE` values and then the `TRUE` values, processing each subset separately.

```
dBase2 <- dBase %>%
  group_by(cod, identity) %>%
  count(have_na=is.na(description)) %>% 
  rename(Total = n)

dBase2 %>%
  filter(!have_na) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  bind_rows(dBase2 %>% filter(have_na)) %>%
  mutate(have_na = c("No", "Yes")[have_na + 1L]) %>%
  adorn_totals('row') 
#   cod identity have_na Total
#   122        2      No     3
#  2801        2      No     4
#  5773        2      No     1
#  9017        1      No     1
#  9018        2      No     3
#  0110        1     Yes     1
#  0294        2     Yes     1
#  3959        2     Yes     1
# Total        -       -    15
```

Comment: Sorry! What I want is both. Can't do it together? I mean, the `FALSE` values showing only the distinct `cod`.

Comment: but then it will show only the "no" values, right?!

Comment: At `1.` I also need to see the "yes" values. But they must not to be distinct.

Comment: @RxT Now I believe I've got it. See the new code at the end.

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself badly. I don't need to see "cod". But when "have_na" is "no", I need to apply `distinct ()` in "cod". When "have_na" is "yes" , "cod" must not to be distinct.

Comment: @RxT Can't you pipe the last result to `select(-cod)` before `adorn_totals`? If you apply `distinct` to one column the output is that column only, the other columns will be gone.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rui Barradas

Answer (score 1):

You almost had the result you were looking for. As Bill stated in the comments you'll have to use an `ifelse` or similar. Like in the below example.

```
dBase %>% 
  mutate(have_na = ifelse(is.na(description), 'yes', 'no')) %>%
  group_by(identity) %>%
  count(have_na) %>%
  rename(Total = n) %>%
  adorn_totals('row')
```